# .htaccess reweite is preventing login

Tags: forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, authentication

I recently tried to implement URL Rewriting but ran into a problem when I attempted to login.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

    ## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Login Form**

```
<form action="assets/php/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form" id="loginform">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br />
    <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" id="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" />
</form>
```

**process_register.php**

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();

$return = 'http://192.168.1.2/blisscount/user/';

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p'];

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        header('Location:'.$return.'index.php');
        die;
    } else {
        header('Location:'.$return.'login.php?error=2');
        die;
    }
} else {
    header('Location:'.$return.'login.php?error=1');
    die;
}
```

Once I submit the form the page redirects to `http://192.168.1.2/blisscount/user/login.php?error=1` Implying it failed in `process_register.php` where it checks if the parameters are set. Using firebug I am able to see that the parameters are in fact being sent.

This is the response I am getting from the call

`Reload the page to get source for: http://192.168.1.2/blisscount/user/assets/php/process_login.php`

**Whats going wrong?**

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: the dump didn't seem to output anything but I just noticed that this is the response I am getting `Reload the page to get source for: http://192.168.1.2/blisscount/user/assets/php/process_login.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to skip `POST` request from external redirects. Use this modified code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

    ## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. It was very well drafted question indeed with all the relevant information to track the problem so +1

Comment: How would I add GET to the exception? I have tried doing `!^(POST|GET)$` with no luck. Then I added `RewriteRule .* - [F,L]` and it still doesn't work. As you can tell I dont know what I am doing with `.htaccess`. I got this info from [link](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#REQUEST_METHOD)

Comment: Hi @anubhava just sending you a bump on my previous comment/question. Really struggling to get this to work. I have tried and tried without any luck.

Comment: Oh so sorry I somehow missed your previous comment. What are you trying to do by blocking GET also as that will block pretty much every web request.

Comment: What i was trying to do was add GET to the acceptation like you helped me add POST. Because now the requests that use GET dont work

Comment: With the current rules I have above, `GET` requests should work fine. can you tell me what is exact URL for which it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes sorry it looks like i changed my code. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as @Christopher was. I just pasted your code into my .htaccess and it worked beautifully. I now have access to the wp-login and all .php extensions are hiden from my website's URLs.

The code for GoDaddy server that worked for me is the following one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## Go Daddy servers need the Options -MultiViews code below
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

    # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

    ## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you!!!